Suspense/Thriller Movie Rented From Redbox in March 2015 about a suspicious college girl
The movie is about a young woman. She is/was enrolled in college, but has come to stay with her dad in a new house. He plans to renovate. I think he was an architect. There was a backstory about a prior family living there, but I don't recall it. At some point it's mentioned that the woman is on psychiatric medication. When strange things happen around the house, she isn't sure if it's real or she's hallucinating.
There was a murder at some point in the past, I believe. I know there is another girl across the road living with her dad. He puts a plastic bag in the back of his truck and the college girl finds a bracelet in the road, but the suspicion she casts on him doesn't come to anything. It turns out there is someone living in a secret room in the house. I think the boy from the old family. He tries to kill her, some stuff happens, and she moves away. And then he's outside the new place and the movie ends.

Sounds like The Intruders with Miranda Cosgrove, which became available around early 2015.

The disturbed twenty year-old Rose Halshford moves with her father, the architect Jerry Halshford, to an old house after the loss of her mother. Soon Rose meets her next door neighbor Leila Markby and she learns about the tragic disappearance of the teenager Rachel that was sheltered by the previous owner of her house, Cheri Garrison and her son Marcus. Rose suspects of Leila's father Howard Markby and she also learns that he had been the prime suspect of the police but proved his innocence. Rose overhears noises in the house but her father believes she is still traumatized by the loss of her mother. Rose also dates the constructor Noah Henry that is refurbishing the house. When strange events happen in the house, Jerry believes Rose is the responsible. Is his daughter really paranoid? 

I'm pretty sure it turns out she's right in the end, and the killer is the previous family's sheltered son. Here's the trailer:




That's the movie! It is was the first one I watched with my girlfriend and it has been driving us crazy. Thank you!
